# DataGrid.selectedIndex memory leak

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, memory, datagrid, memory-leaks

I have noticed a memory leak in a DataGrid, in case I do not select an item, I am able to GC my dataGrid, if there was anything selected then dataGrid cause memory leak...
here is the simpliest example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;

            import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;

            [Bindable]
            private var columns:ArrayList = new ArrayList;

            [Bindable]
            private var dataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                dataProvider.addItem({id:1});

                var column:GridColumn = new GridColumn;
                column.dataField = id;
                columns.addItem(column);

                container.selectedIndex = 0;
            }

            private function gotoOne():void
            {
                currentState = one;
            }

            private function gotoTwo():void
            {
                columns = null;

                currentState = two;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="one"/>
        <s:State name="two"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:Button click="gotoOne()" label="one"/>
    <s:Button click="gotoTwo()" label="two" left="150"/>

    <s:DataGrid id="container" top="30" includeIn="one" itemDestructionPolicy="auto"
                creationComplete="onCreationComplete()" columns="{columns}"
                dataProvider="{dataProvider}"/>
</s:Application>
```

if you comment out line "container.selectedIndex = 0;" DataGrid gets GCed nicely.
Any ideas how to GC DataGrid with selected item?
I am using flex 4.6.0

Comment: Have you tried deselecting the item in `gotoTwo`? `container.selectedIndex = -1`

Comment: I have tried resetting the selection via selectedIndex, selectedItem, selectedIndices, clearSelection(), setSelectedIndex(), setSeelctedCell() and a dozens of other but no luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a memory leak, it is cycle of a live item.

`onCreationComplete` is called when you finish render and display datagrid on the scene, you must add the item on click of the grid( `selectedItem` event).

Comment: hi Daniel, I have just noticed I didnt fully explained the process to get there. 1. wait until scene is rendered, you will notice DataGrid instance in profiler. 2. click button two to remove DataGrid from scene. 3. now the DG instance should vanish (GC) but it is not in case anything has been selected in it